# Having to force scope.apply when using ng-show in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I'm writing a simple tooltip directive where you apply the directive to the item you want the tooltip on. It then builds and appends the tooltip onto the tag where you've applied the directive. The spec calls for it to be click based rather than hover so there are some simple listeners to ng-show/hide the content. It sounds simple but I hit some unexpected hair pulling here as the angular event loop wouldn't fire when I changed the state to show in an element click-hanlder unless I forced a scope.apply. Ditto for hide but I managed a workaround to that by just putting all the code into the ng-click.

Okay enough talk, here's the code:

base tag where the directive is applied

```
<i tooltip text="I'm a tooltip">Target</i>
```

And here's the directive

```
app.directive('tooltip', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
        text: '@'
    },
    template: '<span ng-transclude></span>' + 
    '<i class="tooltip-arrow icon-arrow-up2" ng-show="state.display"></i>' + 
    '<div class="tooltip-container" ng-show="state.display">' + 
    '<span class="tooltip-close" ng-click="state.display = false; $event.stopPropagation();">X</span>' +
    '<p>{{text}}</p></div>',
    controller: function($scope, $element) {
        $scope.state = {
            display: false,
        };


        $element.on('click', function(e) {
            $scope.state.display = true;

            // WHY AM I NEEDED?
            $scope.$apply();

        });
    }
};
});
```

And here's the plunkr to demonstrate, just remove the scope.apply and it'll stop working until you do something to fire the event loop:

http://plnkr.co/edit/mmSAVKkXfIBsoVz9XSKZ

Is this a bug or am I missing some minute point in the angular documentation?

Comment: have you tried angularjs ui tooltip direcitve?
<br/>http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
<br/>I am wondering y u r implementing your own directive?

Comment: This is for an account I'm working on where there are some additional VD/UI/UX behaviors that are outside what angular-ui does. Also, I'd rather not pull in yet another library for something I can write and have control over.

Comment: You are changing scope outside the context of AngularJS. $element.on is a jquery even handler, so Angular needs to know you have made change to the scope variable.

Answer (score 1):

`scope.$apply()` is needed when you use a non-angular event. `elm.on(...)` is part of jQuery so angular can't catch the change. `ng-click` otherwise is part of angular so you dont need to apply anything.

Answer (score 0):

Derp, of course right after posting this I found that putting the click listener on this guy

```
<span ng-transclude ng-click="state.display = true">
```

It works without having to do any scope.apply's. I suppose it's better code as well if I don't have to resort to setting click listeners with angular.element.

Comment: Almost good. you should stick business logic in the controller whenever possible. I'd change the ng-click value to 'onTooltipClicked', and on the controller's scope put the onTooltipClicked function, which will set the state.display to true.